# Ideals and generators being irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on this problem and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with it.

The problem states:"Let F be a field and let J be an ideal in F[x]. Prove that J is prime if its generator is irreducible over F."

I am not sure what "...irreducible over F" means. I've done research and I keep finding problems related to polynomials being irreducible.

I know that a field is a commutative ring with unity in which every non zero element is invertible. An ideal is a nonempty subset that is closed under addition, negatives and it absorbs products. And I know that prime means that "If ab is in J, then a is in J or b is in J.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It means irreducible as an element of the ring $F[x].$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element

Comment: Glad to help!{}

Answer (score 3):

A polynomial is *irreducible over $F$* if it is an irreducible element of $F[x]$.  Here are are some definitions that you may or may not need:

- If R is a commutative ring, a nonzero element $x\in R$ is a *unit* if it is invertible.  For example, in a field every nonzero element is a unit.  The units in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm1$.
- An element $x\in R$ that is nonzero and not a unit is *irreducible* if whenever $x=ab$ with $a,b\in R$ then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.  For instance, the irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are the prime numbers and their negatives.

Here are some examples for polynomials over a field:

- $x^2-1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ because $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ and neither $x+1$ nor $x-1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.
- $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.  (Maybe you should try to prove this!)
- $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{C}$ because $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$ and $x+i$ and $x-i$ are not units in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.